# Using ulong with Math.Pow

Tags: c#, ulong

I have the following code:

```
ulong num = ulong.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
ulong num1 = Math.Pow(num, 2);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'ulong'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Math.Pow` returns `double` which is a floating point number. As `ulong` is integral, assigning a double requires an explicit cast because information is being lost: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#explicit-numeric-conversions

Comment: Well, you are indeed missing a cast. [Math.Pow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow) return double and you will loose some bits of value, so there is an error, and you need to tell compiler "yes, sure, I want cast `double` to `ulong`" by doing `var num1 = (ulong)Math.Pow(num.2);`.

Comment: Also note that floating point math is not exact, so you might get unexpected results. Why don't you just stay in the integer realm and use `num * num`?